# Minimizing Netty memory consumption per socket (millions of connections)

Tags: netty

I'm building a WebSocket proxy fleet that needs to handle tens of millions of concurrent WebSocket connections with the average being around 10 million. Having evaluated various WebSocket libraries I've settled with using Netty.

The average messages pushed over the WebSocket connection are a few hundred bytes in size with the maximum being around 1KB. Each client is sent around one message every 10 seconds from the backend, so the rate of data being sent is small.

The limiting factor for putting more connections on a single server is the memory consumed per connection. Are there any specific configurations or other optimizations I should do to minimize the memory being consumed per connection? I'm running the JVM on Linux.